# Django: List and Display Data from DB

Tags: python, django

I found a code that the urls in django can contain a model, so it can display a db values directly to html, but when i tried it, i got some error in the urls because this code still using patterns, is it possible doing this thing in a newer django?

The Url

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns("myapp.views",
   url(r'^dreamreals/', ListView.as_view(
      template_name = "dreamreal_list.html")),
      model = Dreamreal, context_object_name = ”dreamreals_objects” ,)
```

The HTML

```
{% extends "main_template.html" %}
{% block content %}
Dreamreals:<p>
{% for dr in object_list %}
{{dr.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome, but can you please clarify what *some error* and *newer django* are?

Comment: Pleae see the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example -- you should be able to easily adjust your `urls.py` to match (turn `patterns` into a list and use `path` rather than `url`

Comment: url(r'^dreamreals/', ListView.as_view(template_name = "dreamreal_list.html")), model = Dreamreal, context_object_name = ”dreamreals_objects” ,
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @vahdet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all you've entered are kwargs of `ListView.as_view()` method.

So instead of doing

```
ListView.as_view(
      template_name = "dreamreal_list.html")),
      model = Dreamreal, context_object_name = ”dreamreals_objects” ,)
```

Which is actually syntaxly incorrect, do :

```
ListView.as_view(
      template_name = "dreamreal_list.html",
      model = Dreamreal,
      context_object_name = ”dreamreals_objects”
)
```

Second error, you're setting the context_object_name to `dreamreals_objects`, but in your template you're iterating over `object_list`.

But this method is not really "pretty" and you should really make a `views.py` with your views and then the `urls.py` should only care about making a route.
As pointed in comments, django  2.1+ no longer use `urlpatterns` but `path` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: it's work, thanks sir for the replies and the suggestions

Comment: happy to help, accept the answer if it solved your solution.